# using assign method to add a column to an already-existing table

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the problem, the code and the error that arises. top_10_movies has two columns, which are rating and name.

```
import babypandas as bpd
top_10_movies = top_10_movies = bpd.DataFrame().assign(
Rating = top_10_movie_ratings,
Name = top_10_movie_names
)

top_10_movies
```

> You can use the assign method to add a column to an already-existing
>   table, too. Create a new DataFrame called with_ranking by adding a
>   column named "Ranking" to the table in top_10_movies

```
import babypandas as bpd
Ranking = my_ranking
with_ranking = top_10_movies.assign(Ranking)





TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-a56d9c05ae19> in <module>
      1 import babypandas as bpd
      2 Ranking = my_ranking
----> 3 with_ranking = top_10_movies.assign(Ranking)

TypeError: assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `assign`, it needs a key to assign to, you can do:

```
with_ranking = top_10_movies.assign(ranking = Ranking)
```

Here's a simple example to check:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a','b']})
ranks = [1, 2]

df.assign(ranks) # causes the same error
df.assign(rank = ranks) # works
```